# Error using ColorStateList for a button "String types not allowed (at 'color' with value '1976D2') "

Tags: android, xml, colors

So Im trying to make the background tint color of a button in my activity change according to the state its in, I created a folder unders res, called "color" in which I defined my ColorStateList called "button_states" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="1976D2"/>


<item
    android:color="FFFFFF" />

 </selector>
```

I also went to the activity_main.xml and assigned the Backgroundtint to the ColorStateList like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Mate 1 4 Creds"
            android:id="@+id/button1_1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="71dp"
             />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Leng 1 3 Creds"
            android:id="@+id/button1_2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="71dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/button_states"
              />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Soc 1   3 Creds"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="71dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Ingl 1  3 Creds"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="71dp" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Gmtr 3 Creds"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="71dp" />

    </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Its the second button, sorry i posted the entire xml but im a newbie and maybe theres another mistake there im not seeing maybe u guys could spot it.

but when I compile I get the errors

Error:(5, 24) String types not allowed (at 'color' with value '1976D2').
Error:(9, 24) String types not allowed (at 'color' with value 'FFFFFF').

pointed to the button_states xml. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use color like this android:color="#1976D2"

Answer (score 3):

Change android:color="1976D2" to android:color="#1976D2"